# ggplot2 faceted plot - can't free my scales

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code creates faceted control charts with free scales, thanks to the qicharts2 package.

```
library(qicharts2)
library(tidyverse)

(plot1 <- qic(age,
              data    = tail(cabg, 100), 
              chart   = 'i',
              title   = 'Age of the last 100 patients (I chart)',
              ylab    = 'Years',
              xlab    = 'Patient #',
              facet   = ~ gender, 
              scales  = 'free'))
p1 <- plot1$data
```

[image: Capture1.png]

When I go ahead and customize the ggplot with my own code (see below) I get almost exactly what I want. But, the scales won't free as seen below. Why can't I get them to free like they are above? The `Male` facet want to stay stuck on the `Female` facets scales.

```
ggplot(p1, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_ribbon(ymin = p1$lcl, ymax = p1$ucl, fill = "black", alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_line(color = "black", size = 1) + 
  geom_line(aes(x, cl)) +
  geom_point(color = "black" , fill = "black", size = 2) +
  geom_point(data = p1 %>% filter(sigma.signal == TRUE), color = "red", size = 2) + 
  ggtitle(label = NULL) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  facet_grid(~ facet1, scales = "free") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(
    text = element_text(size = 18), 
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.6), 
    axis.text.y = NULL, 
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14, color = "black", angle = 0))
```

[image: Capture2.png]

Comment: Use `facet_wrap(~ facet1, scales="free")`.

Comment: use "free_y" only if you want the x-axis to remain fixed

Comment: @epi10 do you want to put that as the answer and I'll mark it solved in a bit? I'll go look up the difference between `facet_grid` and `facet_wrap` now.